# Consolidating Terraform Modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I currently have 3 modules which together deploy all the virtual networking in an azure subscription. I want to consolidate this down to one module maintaining the state of resources already deployed.

Any pointers on the best way to achieve this?

Stu

Comment: It's helpful to provide a solution if you put out your Terraform code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides merging the code, which I assume you know, you only have to move all resources to their new path. Use [`terraform state mv`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html) to move resources below e.g. `module.foo.aws_instance.this` to `module.bar.aws_instance.this`:

```
terraform state mv module.foo.aws_instance.this module.bar.aws_instance.this
```

Afterwards, ensure that `terraform plan` is clean.

Feel free to ask another, more specific question, if you run into a concrete problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, that's the starting point I was looking for.

Comment: If it turns out that my answer helped, please use the checkmark on the left to mark the question as solved.

Comment: A bit fiddly with lots of resource, but achieves the desired effect.  Thanks again.